# Stop users from directly accessing and using OOTB Lists

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, javascript, permissions, 2016

There are two type of Users on my Site. Power Users and Normal Users.
I want the Power Users to have access to the OOTB Lists and they can do whatever they want with those List and List Items.

However I have created Custom Forms for other Users and they must go through this flow in order to achieve anything. I don't want them to access any OOTB lists.

Comment: What permissions you have granted to "Normal Users" on this list? which operations they should perform on the list (create/update/delete items, edit list/columns, etc.)?

Comment: Contribute of course. However, I want there interaction to happen only at custom forms level. Any other direct interaction with OOTB views will be for power users only.

Answer (score 0):

Give the normal users to the site read access. If they need to contribute list items, then give them contribute access to those lists by granting them contribute access to the site or those individual lists.

Comment: I guess you misunderstood, I want Power users to use the same list. However, for normal users, I have created custom forms giving them limited control over what they can do. I don't want them to access the Out of the box list views in any possible way.

Comment: I didn't mention the power users, so I'm not sure what you mean. You can give power users different permissions. Please provide more information regarding your custom forms in your question. If the forms use the context of the current user to update the list then they will need at least contribute permission.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using SharePoint server 2016 classic experience, try below suggestions:

**Use Audience Targeting on list views**:

1. Go to list view page.
2. Edit the page and open List web part settings.
3. Add Power users group in "Target Audiences" under "Advanced" section.
4. This way only power users can see the list view & normal users will not see the list view.

Example:

[image]

---

**Use custom JavaScript**:

1. Edit the list view page & Add custom JavaScript using Content Editor or Script Editor web part.
2. In your code, [get currently logged in users groups](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013-get-current-user-group-collection-through-rest-api).
3. If user is part of "Normal users" group (Or not part of "Power users" group), [redirect to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744751/how-do-i-redirect-with-javascript).